# JPA, Can not delete record

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to delete multiple rows(if any) using JPA, and I get **nullpointer** exception. The  parameter and the entity manager is **not** null. Any ideas what might be causing this exception?

P.S The class is annotated @Transactional

```
@Override
public void removeAccount(String id) {
    try {

        int deleteRecords = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE from bankaccount b where b.accountNumber = ?1", BankAccount.class)
                .setParameter(1, accountNumber)
                .executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `ex.getMessage();` for? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Use remove method instead of query, described [Here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11539796/529543

Comment: and `entityManager.createQuery`?

Comment: @matheszabi entity manager find method finds only with primary key, i only have account id to find?

Comment: @nachokk  yes entityManager.createQuery gives nullpointer exception, why?

Comment: Could you send the full stack trace?

Comment: You are also passing in id to the removeAccount method but then using accountNumber to set the query parameter. Have you initialized accountNumber?

Comment: @Spring bankaccount should be BankAccount i think, and did you try using without 2nd parameter BankAccount.class ? also you pass ID and you don't use it

Comment: @nachokk thanks! solution was removing 2nd parameter "BankAccount.class" I will accept it if you answer it

Comment: @Spring ok i answer xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to put second parameter, also i put class name in query. `BankAccount` and `String id` is never used in the method.

```
int deleteRecords = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE from BankAccount b where b.accountNumber = ?1")
                .setParameter(1, accountNumber)
                .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete an entity you should first query it and then pass it to the remove method.

For example if `accountNumber` is the `BankAccounts` primary key:

```
BankAccount account = entityManager.find(BankAccount.class, accountNumber);
entityManager.remove(account);
```

**Update**

If you can not use `primary key` and need to delete multiple entries you can use the code you provided, but do not make a typed query:

```
int numberOfRecords = entityManager
    .createQuery("DELETE from bankaccount b where b.accountNumber = ?1")
    .setParameter(1, accountNumber)
    .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: accountNumber is NOT primary key here, and I will delete multiple records, which is why I prefer to use simple delete query please improve or remove this answer.

Comment: it should be createNativeQuery, not createQuery. .createNativeQuery("DELETE b from bankaccount b where b.accountNumber = ?1")